# How to add breaking views to an Visual Studio SQL Server Database Project

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, database-project

I've created an SQL Server Database Project so that I can capture my database schema and add it to source control.

My problem is that the database contains Views which reference external databases. Given the business and project environment, this is an acceptable solution in the short tomedium term.

Sadly, this stops the database project from compiling, (since it don't contain the external database tables).

What are my options for getting around this error? I'm currently storing the schema in a single generated script, which is a pain to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at creating dacpac files out of the external databases and add them as database references. I did that by using the SQLPackage command line to generate the file, put the files in a "shared" folder (optional, but useful if this pattern persists with other projects), then add a database reference to the project. I recommend removing the variable for the DB name unless it can change in different environments.  I blogged a bit about this here:

http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/10/ssdt-external-database-references.html

Now if it's a truly breaking change, I've done this through post-deploy scripts. Drop/recreate the view and reapply any permissions necessary. That's not ideal, but it can work.